# Socket io timeout connecting to heroku socket io server with custom namespace

Tags: javascript, express, http, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my server located in heroku with socket io with this code, which works when the server is ran locally but, when I try to connect to the same server on herkoku it won't connect and it will give me a timeout.

I've tried setting transport to websocket on the client and it gives me websocket error on chrome and can't establish connection on firefox.

Client side code:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');    
socket = io.connect('https://herokuappurl.com:23840/custom_nsp');//not works
socket = io.connect('localhost:23840/custom_nsp');//works
```

Server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var server = http.listen(PORT,function(){
   print('listening on *:' + PORT);
});
io.of('/custom_nsp').on('connection', function(socket) {
   /*socket.on events*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to version 1.7 at it works now.